# What's that word meaning 'thus more strongly for X'?

Tags: single-word-requests

What's that word meaning 'thus more strongly'? As in X applies to Y, and thus even more strongly to Z. E.g.:

> The body's immune system needs warmth, so adequate heating is good for you (and [this conclusion follows with even more force] for sick people)

I seem to remember that there is such a word, and it's Latin, though I could be wrong.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*a fortiori*

(It has an entry in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_fortiori_argument).)

In Hebrew, we call it a *Kal Vachomer* (if this is true in a lenient case, it is all the more true in a strict case).

Comment: I'm sure this is just me, but I like the other answers a lot better, as I've never heard of this phrase.

Comment: OP did ask for a Latin phrase, but it sounds like something only a lawyer or someone who learned Latin would ever think to say. The other answers sound more natural in everyday speech.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer but I occasionally teach Rhetoric to my high school students.

Comment: @IainElder I *did* learn Latin and I'd never think to say this.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps a simpler, non-Latin phrase?

> Adequate heating is good for you, and **particularly** for sick people

or

> Adequate heating is good for you, and **doubly so** for sick people

Comment: Or *especially*, while we're sticking to the actual words people are most likely to use.

Comment: "Time is an illusion; lunchtime doubly so."

Answer (score 6):

A further option in addition to those already posted:

> Adequate heating is good for you, and **moreso/more so** for sick people.